# codeigniter app failing with HTTP 500 error

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I've created small CI test app.  But it seems to be failing when I try to access the one method.  Actually, now the welcome message doesn't even appear.

**Error Message**

The apache error log doesn't show any error but the access log shows the following message:

```
10.1.1.1 - - [26/Mar/2015:12:31:49 -0500] "GET /ptest/index.php/loadtest/add/100001 HTTP/1.1" 500 205 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
```

**How To Trigger Error:**

Up until a little while ago,  the error was only triggered when I tried to access my custom controller, but now it happens even when I access the default welcome page like so:

```
http://10.1.1.34/ptest/index.php
```

The last thing I remember changing was the autoload.php file because my model wasn't loading properly.  For what its worth, here's all the code:

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Loadtest extends CI_Controller {

        public function index() 
        {
        }
        public function add()
        {
                $data = array(
                   'id' => $this->uri->segment(3,0) , 
                   'fname' => 'john' ,
                   'lname' => 'doe',
                   'password'=> 'test123',
                   'email_address'=>'mytest@gmail.com'
                ); 
                echo('inside controller');
                $this->load->model('loadtest_model');

            $this->loadtest_model->add_user($data);
            $this->load->view('testresults');
      }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class loadtest_model extends CI_Model {

        function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
        }

        public function add_user($data)
        {
                try{
                        echo('inside model');
                        $this->db->insert('system_users',$data);
                }
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                        echo($e);
                }
        }    
}
```

**database.php**

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '10.123.123.123';
$db['default']['username'] = 'postgres';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'testdb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['port'] = 5432;
```

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
$autoload['config'] = array();
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

**How I try to load the app:**

http://10.1.1.34/ptest/index.php/loadtest/add/100001

**Other Comments**

I've also ensured that the pg_hba.conf file on the database server is allowing connections from the "remote" server, where the web app is running.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all         all     10.1.1.0/24     trust
```

Comment: Have you checked the Apache error log or the Codeigniter application log for any errors?

Comment: What version of CI are you using?